# HTML/CSS css boxes and positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS greybox: (When I say greybox, I mean the CSS box I have created that I have made with the color grey as you can see down below.)

```
.navigation-div
{
    margin-top: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
    padding: 0;
    color: #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

This greybox is inside of my header and since this greybox is bigger than it appears, it goes past the header image but doesn't appear.

With this:

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <a class="navigation-div-blur">
       <div class="navigation-div">
            <nav class="navigation">
                <a href="mailto:info@email.com"><img id="mailpicture" src="images/gmail.png"></a>
                <h1 id="mailtext">Mail Us</h1>
                <h1 id="nava">test</h1>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The picture and Mail Us show in the correct position not exposing the box. The test however, when I put it in exposes the box.
Here is the CSS I have behind this

```
#mailtext
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 1230px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
}

#mailpicture
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    float: right;
}

#nava
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

You already saw the box for CSS.

I would like to accomplish either one of two things: Make the CSS box smaller and lower it, or have the CSS correctly position the test along with more elements to stay in the same line as the Mail Us.

NOTE: I have tried for the test margin-top:-pixels, this does not go up high enough and stops going up after a while.

This is what it looks like with the test:
[image: 1]
This is what it looks like without the test:
[image]

As you can notice the first one has a larger box that drops down beneath the header picture. The one without the test has stayed in the header's picture.

Comment: Show us your final result. It can easily identify your question.

Comment: @Abdulla I added in pictures to show the final results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.
First, you should not nest anchors (`<a>`) in other anchor elements.
Using margin to position elements is not a good idea, you are already trying to use `inline-block` to change default `block` display of headers and at the same time you are floating one of your `inline-block` elements to the right.

Adding big margin to the element makes the element use more space and moves next inline element to the new line if it cannot fit in one line with other elements.

If you want to position all your menu items to the right you can use `text- align:right` on your `inline-block` elements to stick them to the right.

If you want your mail element be on the right you may stick to using `float:right` on it, but it would also be easier to just place mail element as the last one in the `nav`

You can nest anchors `<a>` inside headers `<h1>` to create links inside headers

```
<h1 id="mailtext">Mail Us <a href="mailto:info@email.com"><img id="mailpicture" src="images/gmail.png"></a></h1>
```

http://jsbin.com/kazocekoba/1/

```css
.navigation-div
{
    margin-top: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
    padding: 0;
    color: #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #333;
    
    text-align: right;
}
#mailtext
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
   /* margin-left: 1230px;*/
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
}

#mailpicture
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    float: right;
}

#nava
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin-left: 500px;*/
}

/* use padding to separate your navigation elements */

.navigation > * {
  padding-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <a class="navigation-div-blur">
       <div class="navigation-div">
            <nav class="navigation">
                <!-- --><a href="mailto:info@email.com"><img id="mailpicture" src="images/gmail.png"></a>
                <h1 id="mailtext">Mail Us</h1>
                <h1 id="nava">test</h1>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

A bit better solution http://jsbin.com/xunokaviju/1/

```css
.navigation-div
{
    margin-top: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.47);
    padding: 0;
    color: #E3E3E3;
    background-color: #333;
    
    text-align: right;
}
#mailtext
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
   /* margin-left: 1230px;*/
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
}

#mailpicture
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    
    /*float: right;*/
}

#nava
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin-left: 500px;*/
}

/* use padding to pad elements */

.navigation > * {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <a class="navigation-div-blur">
       <div class="navigation-div">
            <nav class="navigation">
                <!-- -->
                <h1 id="nava">test</h1>
                <h1 id="mailtext">Mail Us <a href="mailto:info@email.com"> <img id="mailpicture" src="images/gmail.png"></a> </h1>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: for the navigation div I see you have text-align:right; This is where my navigation bar is going to be and the mail us is going to probably be the only thing going to the right. Could I just bring back the floats to those elements, or put my actual navbar in a div with text align:center;

Comment: I've set `text-align: right` to align descendant `inline-block` elements to the right. If you want your menu to the left/center, just remove/change text align property. If you want float elements, use float, just don't use margins to position elements, and you'll be fine. I suggest you to read some about the box model, you'll understand what margins/floats etc. actually do. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/

Comment: I have come to notice now that the Mail Us and image are in the same line, but from my pictures from my question it was slightly higher. How would I do this? margin-top: with negative pixels doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can play with `vertical-align` https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

In `#mailtext` the `margin-left:1230` is the problem. Keeping your code just as it is the only change you'll have to make looks like this:

```
#mailtext
{   
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
    #mailtext
{
margin-top: 20px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 1230px;   
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
font-style: italic;
}
```

to

```
   #mailtext
{
margin-top: 20px;
display: inline-block;
float:right;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: I have tried this before floating the text to the right, this makes the text go on the line underneath the picture.